# Scrape public posts for a hashtag in Instagram

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, instagram

Is there a way to scrape information on public posts from a hashtag in Instagram, like the caption, number of likes, number of comments etc without providing any login information?

If not can we do it using credentials at least the top posts for a hashtag?

Comment: Is there a way to scrape using the login credentials using some python library?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is possible to extract public data from Instagram using both PHP and Python programming languages. However, it's essential to employ different proxies while doing so; otherwise, Instagram could block your IP due to several successive calls to their platform.

I've implemented this functionality on one of my websites. It enables the extraction of content from any public Instagram profile simply by inputting the username.([instanavigation.io](https://instanavigation.io/))

I hope you find this information helpful. If there are any more details or specific insights you would like to know, please feel free to ask.

Best Regards,
Jim.